# Sharing eth0 to eth1

Tags: pi-2, internet

The situation: Just moved into new student accommodation. With the internet access they allow you to assign 4 MAC Address of devices you wish to have Internet access on, got me thinking if sharing the connection would work without having the add a new device my account. I've tested this under the windows ICS feature as it's working fine.

I've been trying to follow this tutorial, https://rbnrpi.wordpress.com/project-list/wifi-to-ethernet-adapter-for-an-ethernet-ready-tv-new-version/ both the new version and old version but to no luck. 
Either the two IPs do not show up, or the IPTables throws errors along the lines of 'ACCEPT' is invalid.
I've searched for other tutorials but they all seem to provide conflicting steps.

I hoping someone on here has done a similar setup and can offer guidance. What I want to achieve is the internet connection from eth0 (built in Ethernet port) to be shared with a USB to Ethernet adapter (eth1), this eth1 will then be plugged into a switch to allow multiple devices to access under on device.

Later one once this is setup the PI would run a VPN, ensuring all my traffic is running through the VPN.